# Looping function defined inside classes

Tags: python, arrays, class, loops

I have a list defined inside the init function of my class. I want to pass it as a parameter inside a function defined inside the same class. This function is looping, each time it takes a user_input and then performs operation on the list defined as other functions inside the parent class.

How can I do this? Each time either the program takes a new list instead of operating on the old one after each loop, or there is a syntactical error.

This is the parent class and init function:

```
class game:
def __init__(self):
    import random
    self.inducerlist=[0,1,2,3]
    self.myArray=[[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]]
    self.myArray[random.choice(self.inducerlist)][random.choice(self.inducerlist)]=2
```

And this is the function

```
def users_choice(self,user_input,self.myArray=self.myArray):
    if user_input=='u':
        game.up(self)
    elif user_input=='d':
        game.down(self)
    elif user_input=='l':
        game.left(self)
    elif user_input=='r':
        game.right(self)
    while True:
        print self.myArray[0][0],"\t",self.myArray[0][1],"\t",self.myArray[0][2],"\t",self.myArray[0][3],"\n"
        print self.myArray[1][0],"\t",self.myArray[1][1],"\t",self.myArray[1][2],"\t",self.myArray[1][3],"\n"
        print self.myArray[2][0],"\t",self.myArray[2][1],"\t",self.myArray[2][2],"\t",self.myArray[2][3],"\n"
        print self.myArray[3][0],"\t",self.myArray[3][1],"\t",self.myArray[3][2],"\t",self.myArray[3][3],"\n"
        user_input = raw_input("u for upward direction, d for downwards, l for left and r for Right")
        game.users_choice(self,user_input,self.myArray=self.myArray)
        self.listfori = []
        self.listforj = []
        count = 0
        for i in range(0,4):
            for j in range(0,4):
                if self.myArray[i][j]==0:
                    count+=1
                    self.listfori.append(i)
                    self.listforj.append(j)
        if count > 0:
            if count > 1:
                randomindex = listfori.index(random.choice(listfori))
                self.myArray[listfori[randomindex]][listforj[randomindex]]=2
            else:
                self.myArray[listfori[0]][listforj[0]]=2
        else: 
            break
            print "Game over"
```

Comment: You cannot refer to `self` within the default value of a method parameter: those get evaluated at the time the class is originally defined, long before any instances of the class can possibly exist.

Comment: You also can't have a parameter name with a dot. `self.myArray` is not a valid argument name. I don't believe that your function gets interpreted without any errors

Comment: But if we don't link the array with self, the different functions won't be able to recognise and perform operations  on the same list. 


Anyways, I solved the problem, I made the loop through the while operation, instead of looping the whole function.